# Is this $2 \times 2$ matrix a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I have the following vector space here with a subset of $W$ of $V$:

> $V=M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}),W=\begin{bmatrix}x & y\\ 0 & -x+2y\\\end{bmatrix}|x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

I have to show if this is a subspace or not.

$1)$ The $0$ condition is safisfied obviously if $x=y=0$.

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & -(0)+2(0)\\\end{bmatrix}|x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}|x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$2)$ Multiplication by a scalar is defined of course.

$\begin{bmatrix}cx & cy\\ 0 & -cx+2cy\\\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & y_1\\ 0 & -x_1+2y_1\\\end{bmatrix}$

For some choice of scalar $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Closure under addition is something I am not sure about. If I add an arbitrary term to the $0$ in the matrix, I don't get $0$ as it was defined in the original matrix. Does that mean I don't have a subspace? I need some clarification on this. Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can write $$W = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\right\},$$ which makes it a subspace, because the span of any subset of a vector space is a subspace.

Comment: Yup. That works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W$ is a subspace. Note that $\begin{bmatrix}x & y\\ 0 & -x+2y\\\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}x' & y'\\ 0 & -x'+2y'\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u & v\\ 0 & -u+2v\\\end{bmatrix}$
 where $u=x+x'$ and $v=y+y'$.

Comment: No. I get that. But don't I need to add a non zero vector to $0$? Why can I just add $0$ instead of some arbitrary vector?

Comment: @FutureMathperson I took two arbitrary elements of $W$ and showed that their sum is also in $W$. That is what is required. The lower left entry always remains $0$ in this proof.

Comment: Yeah. Point made. Thanks! I don't know why that didn't click at first.